# Joint and conditional distribution of summed sequential normal random variables

Tags: linear-transformations, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

there are similar questions asking about the bivariate case, but I am interested in a general case where n > 2.

Let's say we have $X_1,..., X_i$  iid $N(0,1)$, and for $j=1,...,n$:

$$\sum_{i=1}^j X_i = X_1+X_2+...+ X_j =Y_j $$

First I want to find the joint distribution of Y's.

I understand that each $Y_j$ ~ $N(\mu_1 + ...+\mu_j, \sigma^2_1+...\sigma^2_j)$ since the $X_i$'s are independent.

My idea is that the joint distribution of $Y_1,...Y_n$ ~ $MVN(0,\Sigma)$ where for the example of n=3:

$$ \Sigma=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    var(Y_1,Y_1) & cov(Y_1,Y_2) & cov(Y_1,Y_3) \\
    cov(Y_2,Y_1) & var(Y_2,Y_2)  & cov(Y_2,Y_3)  \\
    cov(Y_3,Y_1)  & cov(Y_3,Y_2)  & var(Y_3,Y_3) \\
    \end{bmatrix} 
=     \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 2  & 2  \\
    1  & 2  & 3 \\
    \end{bmatrix} 
=\sigma_i^2\mathbf{I}
$$

i.e. $cov(Y_j,Y_{j+1})=cov(X_1+...+X_j,X_1+...+X_i+X_{j+1})=var(X_1)+...+var(X_j)$

because $cov(X_s,X_{s+1})=0$ for independent $X_s$'s

If I apply the formulas I've seen, then  the conditional distribution of $Y_{j+1}$ given $Y_j$ would have

$ \mu=\mu_{j+1}+\Sigma_{j,(j+1)}\Sigma^{-1}_{jj}(\textbf{y}_j-\mu_j)$

and covariance $\Sigma_{j,j+1}=\Sigma_{jj}-\Sigma_{j,j+1}^T\Sigma_{j+1,j+1}^{-1}\Sigma_{j,j+1}$

However, I'm having a hard time figuring out what that would look like all spelled out for this special case where $Y_j=\sum_{i=1}^j X_i $. Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: For every $j$, $Y_{j+1}=Y_j+X_{j+1}$ with $X_{j+1}$ standard normal independent of $Y_j$ hence, for every $y$, conditionally on $Y_j=y$, $Y_{j+1}$ is normal $N(y,1)$.

Comment: @Did That makes a lot of sense, thanks! I thought perhaps the conditional distribution warranted something much more involved, but this simplification was helpful.

Comment: @Did If we were to seek instead the conditional distribution of $X_{k+1}$ given $X_1,....,X_k$ would it be a similar scenario where $X_{k+1}$ is distributed $N(\sum_{k=1}^kX_i , 1)$?

Comment: ?? The conditional distribution of $X_{k+1}$ given $X_1,....,X_k$ is equal to the unconditional distribution of $X_{k+1}$ since $X_{k+1}$ is independent of $X_1,....,X_k$.